# How to insert into SQL Database Table with QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to insert into my SQL database using QT. I have been successful with other SQL commands like delete. But here Nothing is added to my database. I am wondering if maybe there is a syntax error somewhere.

```
QSqlQuery task;

task.prepare("insert or replace into animals(name, type, breed, gender, age, lifespan, noise, intelligence, adaptability, personality, diet, environment, pastOwners, timeDedication, costDedication, medication, reproductability, appetite, energyLevel, weight, height) values ('" + name + "', '" + type + "','" + breed + "','" + gender + "', " + age + ", " + lifespan + ", " + noise + ", " + intelligence + ", " + adaptability + " ,'" + personality + "', '" + diet + "', '" + environment + "', " + pastOwners + ", " + timeDedication + ", " + costDedication + ", " + medication + ", " + reproductability + ", '" + appetite + "', " + energyLevel + ", " + weight + ", " + height + ");");

task.exec();
```

Comment: some of your field names have ', some have not. Maybe you should check the return value of tesk.exec() and in case it's false, check task.lastError() etc.

Answer (score 4):

For [prepared query](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare) you need write something like this:

```
  QSqlQuery query;
  query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
              "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
  query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
  query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");       
  query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
  query.exec();
```

Binding values will help avoid sql injection.

Comment: @transistor, I think you wanted to write it in a comment to the question

Comment: ups, sorry! moved that